# Completely Full /system on CM11?

Tags: file-system, cyanogenmod

I installed CM11 from [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-s/4g-development/cm-11-0-10-2-krt16s-jss15q-nexus-4g-t2427140) on my old Nexus S 4g, thinking I could use it as a tiny server or something. However, it seems that the /system mountpoint, where things like /etc live, is ~100% full:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   193.1M   136.0K   193.0M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         193.1M     0.0K   193.1M   4096
/mnt/asec              193.1M     0.0K   193.1M   4096
/mnt/obb               193.1M     0.0K   193.1M   4096
/mnt/fuse              193.1M     0.0K   193.1M   4096
/efs                     6.8M     1.6M     5.2M   4096
/cache                 469.5M     2.3M   467.2M   4096
/system                503.9M   503.9M     8.0K   4096
/data                 1007.9M   351.4M   656.5M   4096
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard0    13.3G     6.8G     6.5G   4096
/mnt/secure/asec        13.3G     6.8G     6.5G   4096
/storage/sdcard0        13.3G     6.8G     6.5G   4096
```

Is this normal, or a strange feature of the particular rom I have flashed?

Is there any way to expand /system without wiping my device?

Can I do an overlay mount and have files in some other directory automatically appear in /system?

Can I take the rom zip I have and modify its install scripts somehow, so that when I flash it I get a bigger /system?

Is there something I can safely delete to free up space on /system?

How do I effectively administer a Linux system where no files can be created under /etc?